# Flexbox within another flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So am using flexbox to create this follow layout but am having a bit of trouble with wanting the follow button to reach the other side of the page. I tried using flexbox the position/move it to the other side of the container but it does not work I even tried nesting inside another container but it does work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.follow__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.follow__container .follow__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 35rem;
}

.follow__content {
  position: relative;
}

.follow__content img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: .0123rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.follow__content .heading-tag {
  margin-left: 0.423rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.follow__tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
  <div class="follow__content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">

    <div class="heading-tag">
      <h2>Mr.Crow</h2>
      <p># Puzzle solver</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>

    </div>


    <div class="follow__tag">
      <a href="#">follow</a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? do you mean to let the follow link to be on top? or to be on the left?

Comment: yea i want it to move to the left and am wondering why flexbox doesnt work it only align it vertically not horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .follow__tag inside css

```
.follow__tag {
    order: -1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

With order property that you add to a child element of an flex parent you can say which one in order should be this item, with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add new div to make the two div(with heading_tag and follow_tag class) to change direction accordingly either using flex:row or flex:row-reverse . also add flex:50% to the both heading_tag and follow_tag class.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

.follow__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.follow__content {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #fff;

    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 12px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 35rem;
    
}

.separate-heading-and-follow-tag {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    
}

.heading-tag {

    flex:50%;
    padding-left:5px;
    
    
}
.image-tag {

    flex:50%;
    padding-left:5px;
    
    
}
.follow__tag {

    flex:50%;
    padding-right:10px;
    
}

.follow__content img {
    width: 4.5rem;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-left: .0123rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.follow__content .heading-tag {
    margin-left: 0.423rem;
    color: #000000;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(3) {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
    <div class="follow__content">
        <div class="separate-heading-and-follow-tag">
            <div class="heading-tag">
                <h2>Mr.Crow</h2>
                <p># Puzzle solver</p>
                <p>Most Popular</p>
            </div>

            <div class="image_tag">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="follow__tag">
                    <a href="#">follow</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i see so your basically saying i need to nest them in order to move the follow btn

Comment: yes, that is what i want to say , nest it. tq

Comment: ok i did what you said but it does push add any space between the heading-tag and the follow i can only move vertically not horizontally

Comment: do you mean you want to add a little space between heading_tag and follow_tag ?

Comment: yea i want to do that

Comment: add padding-left to heading_tag class ( padding-left : 5px; ) should solve the spacing issue. you can add the margin to your need accordingly then.

Comment: hi @Kai, the answer has been updated and already got some space between the heading_tag and follow_tag. if that answered your question, please consider to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe you are asking for. You needed to put the flex on follow_content class. Then just justify-content to space the items.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.follow__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.follow__container .follow__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 35rem;
}

.follow__content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.follow__content img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: .0123rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.follow__content .heading-tag {
  margin-left: 0.423rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.follow__tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
 
  <div class="follow__content">
   <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">

    <div class="heading-tag">
      <h2>Mr.Crow</h2>
      <p># Puzzle solver</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>

    </div>
   </div>


    <div class="follow__tag">
      <a href="#">follow</a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS for debugging. This will show how your elements are placed.
- if you want 'follow' to the left, why did you place it last in the parent element, making it go right?
- `justify-content` is default `flex-start`, as you placed flexbox container `.follow__content` inside center justified flexbox container `.follow__container` all the elements got stuck together.

What you actually want is either `justify-content: space-evenly or space-between or space-around`.

Check the below snippet:

```css
* {
  outline: 1px dashed
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.follow__container,
.follow__content { /* both are flexbox containers */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.follow__container {
  /* center all content of main container */
  justify-content: center;
}
.follow__content {
  /* evenly space all content */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
/*  justify-content: space-between;/**/
/*  justify-content: space-around; /**/
/* Take your pick */
}

.follow__container .follow__content {
  background-color: Linen; /* just for debugging */
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 35rem;
}

/* obsolete
.follow__content {
  position: relative;
}
/**/

.follow__content img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: .0123rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.follow__content .heading-tag {
  margin-left: 0.423rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

/* obsolete
.follow__tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
/**/
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
  <div class="follow__content">

    <div class="follow__tag">
      <a href="#">follow</a>
    </div>

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">

    <div class="heading-tag">
      <h2>Mr.Crow</h2>
      <p># Puzzle solver</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "spacer" element. Just before the `follow__tag` div, add a new div:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

In the CSS, add a rule:

```
.spacer {
     flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

The `flex-basis` "...sets the initial main size of a flex item."

You can use this to your advantage and set the size of the `spacer` to `100%`, meaning it will fill all available space inside the flex container. This pushes the follow button all the way to the right of the page.

[Flex-basis on MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.follow__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.follow__container .follow__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 35rem;
}

.follow__content {
  position: relative;
}

.follow__content img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: .0123rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.follow__content .heading-tag {
  margin-left: 0.423rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.heading-tag p:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.follow__tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.spacer {
   flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__container">
  <div class="follow__content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="">

    <div class="heading-tag">
      <h2>Mr.Crow</h2>
      <p># Puzzle solver</p>
      <p>Most Popular</p>

    </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div class="follow__tag">
      <a href="#">follow</a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yea think I get it now by adding a "spacer"  and setting the width or flex basis to it , it makes it that space 100% and pushes the content to the left